# Pre-alpha Mapbox integration into Eclipse Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, mapbox

I have an existing Eclipse android project that I would like to use the pre-alpha MapboxSDK with. I have tried using gradle to try to build the library into my project, but have been unsuccessful. Is there someone out there that would be able to detail a step by step procedure for importing and integrating the SDK into an existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to ask would be [on the issue tracker for the project](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk), and to share the specific error that you happen upon in trying to set the project up.